# python MPI for dictionary iteration

Tags: python, dictionary, mpi

I would like to split the iteration of dictionary using MPI (mpi4.py)(message passing interface).

for example,

```
from mpi4py import MPI
comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
rank = comm.Get_rank()
size = comm.Get_size()

tmp_list = []
for key, value in some_dict.items():
    tmp_values = some_function(key,value)
    tmp_list.append(tmp_values)
```

there is some simple code.
How do i compose the MPI code for the iteration.

Comment: The acronym "MPI" is overloaded.  You're going to have to go into more detail about what you want.

Comment: Also, don't use `dict` as name, it's built-in function.

Comment: what do you mean `split the iteration of dictionary using MPI`. Do you wish to scatter data across cores and then iterate over

Answer (score 1):

You will first need to convert the dict into a list and then divide the list into a number of processes that you will be using. This is necessary so that `comm.scatter` can send parts of data across all processes. And then final results could be gathered using `comm.gather`

script.py

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from mpi4py import MPI

comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
size = comm.Get_size() # get number of processes
rank = comm.Get_rank() # get the current rank of process

def some_fun(x,y): # some random function
    return x+y

def chunkIt(seq, num): #function to chunk list into {size} parts for scatter to work
    avg = len(seq) / float(num)
    out = []
    last = 0.0

    while last < len(seq):
        out.append(seq[int(last):int(last + avg)])
        last += avg

    return out

some_dict = {i: i**2 for i in range(100)} # some random data to work on

if rank == 0:
    data = chunkIt(list(some_dict.items()), size) # convert dict into list first and then divide the data into {size} parts
    # print(f"rank: {rank} / data: {data}")
else:
    data = None
    
data = comm.scatter(data, root=0) # scatter the data accross given processes
print(f"rank: {rank} / data: {data}\n")

sub_dict = dict(data) # convert the list into dict

tmp_list = [] #local to each process
for key, value in sub_dict.items():
    tmp_values = some_fun(key, value)
    tmp_list.append(tmp_values)
  
tmp_list = comm.gather(tmp_list, root=0) # gathering data from all procs to root proc
if rank == 0:
    print(f"length of tmp_list on rank: {rank} is: {len(tmp_list)}")
    print(f"tmp_list: {tmp_list}") #tmp_list is list ot lists. make sure to convert it into required ds 
else:
    assert tmp_list is None
```

make it executable using `chmod`

`chmod +x script.py`

and then run

`mpiexec -n 4 script.py`

-n is the number of processes to run

**Note: I am using ubuntu 16.04 and python 3.7.10 and mpi4py==3.0.3**